# Sampling a statsmodel KDEMultivariate

Tags: statsmodels

I have been exploring kernel density methods in statsmodel that allow categorical variables but it seems that, unlike scikit learn kernel density implementation, there are no methods to generate samples from the distribution. I have already look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513711/generating-random-numbers-for-testing-a-kernel-density-estimate) but the examples only use one single continuous feature.